# How to access fields/methods created by javassist

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I have a simple java application with a class name `TestApp`. I am writing a java agent to do some profiling on my java application using javassist. I have added a method and a field to a TestApp class of my test application like this:

```
CtClass ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get("TestApp");

// create a field
CtField f = CtField.make("int testField = 1;", ctClass);
ctClass.addField(f);

//create a method
CtMethod newmethod = CtNewMethod.make("public void test() { System.out.println(\"printing\"); }", ctClass);
ctClass.addMethod(newmethod);
```

The problem is even though I have created and added them to my `TestApp` class using this agent I still can not access them from any other member of my `TestApp` class. So my question is how can I access this method and field created using java agent's transform method from other members of `TestApp` class?

The way I was trying to do it was using `insertBefore` which should insert the line of source code at the beginning of all the methods of `TestApp` class something like this:

```
CtMethod ctMethod[] = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for (CtMethod method : ctMethod) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"field value \" + testField);");
}
ctClass.writeFile();
```

but this fails coz it cant access the `testField`, I can only use them if I create local variable using `method.addLocalVariable`. So is there any way we can use global fields created like above inside `insertBefore`/`insertAfter` methods and if no is there any alternate fix to this so we can access this field from original java application?

Also another question how to debug `javassist` code? coz I dont see any outputs or errors if my `javassist` agent code fails

Any suggestion/recommendation/help would be very appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same class pool? Otherwise, Javassist loads the byte code from the class path where you did not alter it.

Comment: yes I am using the same class pool I realized the typos I made in the code and I have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The mistake was when I was trying to access the static field created by the agent using javassist in my main class I was just giving the name of the Field inside `insertBefore` like

```
method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"field value \" + testField);");
```

Which should have been

```
method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"field value \" + <Complete Class name>.testField);");
```